# Insert marker in google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to insert a marker in google map after clicking button. Actually I've passed parameter to addmarker() function. Still it is not showing the marker. I'm giving my source code.

```
function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(23.684994000000000000,           90.356330999999950000);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: myLatlng
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}

function addmarker(Clientlatitude, Clientlongitude) {
    var latilongi = new google.maps.LatLng(Clientlatitude, Clientlongitude);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latilongi,
        map: this
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

<input id="btnMarkerInseart" type="button" value="Insert" onclick='<%# "addmarker(" +Eval("latitude") + ", " +Eval("longitude") + ");" %>' />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare your map variable outside of the initialize function, and then refer to it in your addmarker function when creating the marker, like this:

```
var map;

function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(23.684994000000000000,           90.356330999999950000);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: myLatlng
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}

function addmarker(Clientlatitude, Clientlongitude) {
    var latilongi = new google.maps.LatLng(Clientlatitude, Clientlongitude);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latilongi,
        map: map
    });
}
```